# Почему var равно NaN (значение из input, формула расчета)

Tags: javascript, input, nan

Здравствуйте, если кто сможет направте на путь истинны, хочу вывести в блок значение посчитаное на основе данных взятых из input. Воожу значение , затем по формуле чситаем значение и результат выводим на екран.. пишет при выводе NaN, а если подставляешь формулу все нормально... вот такой код:

```
var TU134a_63957_NPE = document.getElementById('TU134a_63957_NPE'); 
var TU134a_63957_nazya4eniy_resurs = 9000;     
var TU134a_63957_ostatok_resurs = TU134a_63957_nazya4eniy_resurs - 
parseInt(TU134a_63957_NPE.value); 

press.onclick = function() {
document.getElementById("display").innerHTML =  TU134a_63957_ostatok_resurs;
 };
```

---

```js
var TU134a_63957_NPE = document.getElementById('TU134a_63957_NPE').value; 
var TU134a_63957_nazya4eniy_resurs = 9000;   

TU134a_63957_ostatok_resurs = parseInt(TU134a_63957_nazya4eniy_resurs) -parseInt(TU134a_63957_NPE); 
 
var press = document.getElementById('press'); 

press.onclick = function() {
    document.getElementById("display").innerHTML =  TU134a_63957_ostatok_resurs;
};
```

```css
#press{
  cursor:pointer;
  margin-top:5px;
  margin-bottom:5px;
}
```

```html
<input id="TU134a_63957_NPE">

<div id="press">Отнять</div>

<div id="display"></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Потому что Вы делаете вычисления, когда инпут еще пустой.

```js
 
var press = document.getElementById('press'); 
press.onclick = function() {
  var TU134a_63957_NPE = +document.getElementById('TU134a_63957_NPE').value; 
  var TU134a_63957_nazya4eniy_resurs = 9000;   
  var TU134a_63957_ostatok_resurs = TU134a_63957_nazya4eniy_resurs - TU134a_63957_NPE; 

  document.getElementById("display").innerHTML = TU134a_63957_ostatok_resurs;
};
```

```css
#press{
  cursor:pointer;
  margin-top:5px;
  margin-bottom:5px;
}
```

```html
<input id="TU134a_63957_NPE">

<div id="press">Отнять</div>

<div id="display"></div>
```

Comment: ЗАРАБОТАЛО! Урааааааа!!!

Comment: Большое спасибо Бро!

Answer (score 2):

Поправил первую строку таким образом:

```
var TU134a_63957_NPE = document.getElementById('TU134a_63957_NPE').value;
```

**Результат:**

```js
var TU134a_63957_NPE = document.getElementById('TU134a_63957_NPE').value; 
var TU134a_63957_nazya4eniy_resurs = 9000;   

TU134a_63957_ostatok_resurs = parseInt(TU134a_63957_nazya4eniy_resurs) -parseInt(TU134a_63957_NPE); 
 
var press = document.getElementById('press'); 

press.onclick = function() {
    document.getElementById("display").innerHTML =  TU134a_63957_ostatok_resurs;
};
```

```css
#press{
  cursor:pointer;
  margin-top:5px;
  margin-bottom:5px;
}
```

```html
<input id="TU134a_63957_NPE" value="5">

<div id="press">Отнять</div>

<div id="display"></div>
```

Comment: @Данил спасибо, все хорошо. Только ты уже заранее дал input значение 5.      <input id="TU134a_63957_NPE" value="5">       А если его убрать и  брать значение из того что ввел пользователем получается NaN